# How to setup SAP CRM 7.0 trial version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sap-crm

I need to install **SAP CRM 7.0** trial version on virtual machine for development and testing. I am new to SAP CRM. Kindly guide me how to obtain the above specified version of SAP CRM. Also provide information if this version of SAP CRM is available on AWS cloud as a trail.

Comment: Can you be more specific?
What products you need? 
http://www.sap.com/software-free-trials/index.html